# Is it possible to specify symbology of a shapefile in R?

Tags: r, arcgis, shapefile

I am creating shapefiles from rasters (Myraster) in R using:

```
TESTPOLY<-rasterToPolygons(Myraster,dissolve = TRUE)
```

Then I write it to a shapefile

```
shapefile(TESTPOLY,"TESTPOLYWGS84.shp")
```

I have read this shapefile into ESRI's ArcMap and I can change the symbology of the attribute (maximum temperature) to 'graduated colours' using a chosen colour ramp. I can also remove the outline of each of the polygon calsses (which makes the map look 'nicer').

My problem is that i have to create a large amount of these shapefiles and I want to automate the symbology changes in R. Is that possible? I see in ArcMap, that it is possible to use the symbology from one layer for another. In principle, could I carry out my symbology changes in Arcmap, then 'copy' the formatting and use it in R?
I realise that this is not a reproducible example, but I haven't found any information about doing this in the usual 'stack' channels.

Comment: For ESRI-realted questions you might get more feedback from https://gis.stackexchange.com/ . Somewhat related, though targeting QGIS and Geopackage - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377634/qgis-geopackage-export-of-layer-symbology , i.e. if (**if**) ArcMap can store symbologies in shapefiles and also load from there, you might want to check added attributes and perhaps add the same set yourself in R.